# How to set selectable image when cropzone is unselectable using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js+darkroom.js for cropping an image.How to set selectable image when cropping rectangle should be unselectable.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you mind adding some code?  What do you mean by... "How to set selectable image when cropping rectangle should be unselectable."?  Are you saying the cropping rectangle does not work?